# Unable to create pipeline even having write permissions on github,how to fix that?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

I have write permissions to the repository, and I can create branches, create pull requests and even merge them also.
But, when creating pipeline on azure, I get this error:

[image: pipeline adding error]

What I need to add more in settings of github or azure to fix this?

Comment: read the article. Read your Picture. It states that github does not have enough permission to create this

Comment: Ok, I can't give admin access to repo. So provided write access. I can update any branch in it, including master branch. But still issue persists. That's what even I mentioned in the question. So, which permission need to be added to it? Please don't just say 'manage hooks'. Please share the exact steps to provide this.

Comment: if you dont have enough rights then it will imho not work. i already tried similar with cloudflare and it worked ootb.